# Laravel Environment confusion

Tags: php, apache, laravel, laravel-5

Ok, so I thought I understood this, but it seems I don't have complete understanding of it.

I've just created an app on my local machine. I had a local `.env` file storing my local environment variables. I understand that when you commit the app to the server with git, the `.env` file isn't pushed, and that you should set the environment values on the server.

Well, I'm using DigitalOcean, and I have created a new virtual host file, and set the environment variables in there using the `SetEnv APP_ENV local` syntax.

When I access the site through the browser, I know it's picking up the env values because I get an error message saying that the base table isn't found, and the database name is what is set in my environment variables. This is fine, because I haven't run migrations yet.

However, When I ssh into the server, and run `php artisan migrate`, it appears to not be picking up the Env values. I assume this is because artisan is not running through an apache virtual host.

Does this mean I need to create a `.env` file which will store my database details etc? If so, what's the point in setting the environment variables in the virtual host file, and not just have a single `.env` file? By setting values in the Virtual Host config file, and also a `.env` file, I'm duplicating environment variables, which is surely bad practice?

If I shouldn't create another `.env` file for the server, how do I specify the environment values to use within artisan?

I hope I explained the question well enough, but if I haven't, or I need to clear something up, please ask.

Comment: You do need a .env file per environment you will be running laravel in. Why are you setting environment values in the VHost files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a `.env` file per environment that Laravel will run in. It is perfectly acceptable to have a `.env` for your local, and a different `.env` on your staging environment, etc, etc.

I am not clear from your question why you need to put variables in your vhost files. Just create a `.env` for the staging and a `.env` for the production environments on their respective servers. If you are building from automated scripts (like puppet or similar) the `.env` are intentionally simple enough that they are easy to create from scripts.

You can even have a few server examples `.env` stored in your repo named like `.env.production-example` so you know what your servers should look like (obviously without actually storing credentials in there).

Comment: Thanks for clearing it up for me, I guess I had got it into my head `.env` files weren't used on the production server after reading the installation documentation (where it states `However, your .env file should not be committed to your application's source control`), and seeing that other people had placed the environment vars in htaccess files. As long as it's fine to put in .env files, that would be preferrable as it's the simplist option. Thanks again :)

Comment: No problem. Yeah the docs feel a bit clunk about that point. Maybe also check this one out: https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-5-fundamentals/episodes/6#

Comment: @Chris, I've just deleted my answer. I had the same idea as Phil about `.env` files, especially due to 12-factor saying about environment vars. It always seemed to me that having sensitive settings in a file wasn't safe.

Comment: @GustavoStraube Yeah it can be a bit misleading, but at the end of the day they do need to be stored somewhere. Have a watch of the video in my comment above (it's only 5 mins) from Jeff at Laracasts. Hopefully it should clear things up. The main thing is that your passwords shouldn't end up in version control. And on that, it's important to note that the `.env` should be above root - so outsiders can't directly access them